# Dissect, sort and compare arrays

Tags: php

I have the two following arrays:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:2:"98";i:1;s:2:"98";i:2;s:2:"89";i:3;s:2:"99";}

a:4:{i:0;s:11:"Musculation";i:1;s:3:"Gym";i:2;s:22:"Production in HTML/CSS";i:3;s:9:"Endurance";}
```

Each array has 4 values that are correlated. I want to display only three values from second array that have the highest correlating number values from first array:-

Endurance - 99

Musculation - 98

Gym - 98

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `array_multisort` to sort the text according to the corresponding numbers

```
array_multisort($numbers, SORT_DESC, SORT_NUMERIC, $text);
```

Take the first three values.

```
$result = array_slice($text, 0, 3);
```

If you want to show the numbers with the text, the keys will still match up, so you can iterate the text array and use its key to get the right value from the number array.

```
foreach ($text as $key => $title) {
    echo "$title: $numbers[$key]\n";
}
```

Comment: Given that the numbers in the `$numbers` array are actually strings, you'll probably want to add a `SORT_NUMERIC` flag to the `array_multisort` so that `9` doesn't sort higher than `80`.

Comment: Oh, good catch, @Nick. I didn't notice they were strings. I'll edit it when I get back to a keyboard. Trying to edit on my phone usually annoys me